# how to push an empty string into an array if user doesn't select any of the radio button

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

While creating quiz app I got stuck on one problem:

If the user selects the radio button I want to push its value into an empty array and if the user selects none I want to push a single empty string to an array without breaking the indexing chain.

I tried this using a `for...of` loop:

- When I select the radio the array gets full of values like this: `["value"," "," "," "]`
- When I select none it gets filled like this: `[" "," "," "," ]`

I know the problem but don't know how to fix it.

```js
for(let option of allOptions){
  if(option.checked){
    selectedAnswer.push(option.value);
  }
  if(!option.checked){
    selectedAnswer.push(" ")
  } 
}
```

Comment: does your radio group consist on 4 items?

Comment: Quick fix of your approach: declare variable as `""`, iterate over all options and overwrite the var if checked. Now push var. Better approach: read `[theform].[theradiogroupname].value`, which contains the value of whatever is checked or an empty string: https://jsfiddle.net/e4vuq20m/

Comment: after your edit: you are checking option by option and pushing everyone (whether checked or not). You'd better be finding what one is checked among all of them, and pushing that. If none is checked, then push an empty string (after the loop)

Comment: yes it have 4 options

Answer (score 0):

## For Single Option :-

```js
// lets target all the radio button
let options  = document.getElementsByName("option");

// suppose option 1 has clicked
options[0].checked = true

// initiate our checked option with an array containing a empty string
let checkedOpttion = [""];

for( i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        if( options[i].checked ) {
          
          // if an option has clicked insted of pushing value we are gonna reset the variable with a new array containg that options value
          checkedOpttion = [options[i].value]
        }
    }

console.log(checkedOpttion)
```

```html
<input type="radio"  name="option" value="01" >
<label for="male">option 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="02">
<label for="female">option 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="03">
<label for="female">option 3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="04">
<label for="female">option 4</label><br>
```

## For Multiple Option

```js
// lets target all the radio button
let options  = document.getElementsByName("option");




// suppose option 1 and option 2 has clicked
options[0].checked = true
options[1].checked = true

// initiate our checked option with an array 
let checkedOpttion = [];

for( i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
        if( options[i].checked ) {
          checkedOpttion.push(options[i].value)
        }
    }
    
    // If you want to push an empty string if none the option checked then
    
    if(checkedOpttion.length === 0){
    checkedOpttion.push("")
    }
    
    // if you dnn't want comment the above one if clause

console.log(checkedOpttion)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="01"  name="option" value="01" >
<label>option 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="02" id="02" >
<label>option 2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="03" id="03" >
<label>option 3</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="04" id="04" >
<label>option 4</label><br>
```

Comment: i tried this and it works well for only one quiz question and when checkedoption  will contain one value then the  length will increase and it will not meet another length ===0

Answer (score 0):

I think [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will be wonderful for your case, because it will allow you to swap existing values inside the array in one single action.

Just pass along the index to your callback function

To add a "value" to any index in the array

```
selectedAnswer.splice(index, 1, "value");
```

and to remove

```
selectedAnswer.splice(index, 1, "");
```

Notice that calling `.splice` will modify the original array and will return any of the removed values from the array.

Example:

```
// HTML
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">

// JS
document.getElementById("cb").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
        selectedAnswer.splice(index, 1, "value");
    } else {
        selectedAnswer.splice(index, 1, "");
    }
});
```

Comment: will you please explain me more.         NOTE:  i need to maintain the indexing of array no matter if the user checks or not So for that reason i have to push an empty string to maintain the indexing.  so later on  i can access what the user have clicked in the particular question and match it with the correct answer in my following data structure[   {  } ].

Comment: Invoking splice with 3 parameters like that won't change your indexing (the array length will remain the same), splice will replace `1` element in index `index` with `"value"` or `""`. use `onchange` to call a function and pass the right values for the right checkbox

Answer (score -1):

Maybe will help use else instrad second if

```
 if(option.checked){
     selectedAnswer.push(option.value);
   } else {
     selectedAnswer.push(" ")
   }
```